# Send Discord webhook is VBS

Tags: vbscript, discord

Is there a way to send a Discord webhook in VBS?
What I've tried:

```
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "POST", "(my webhook here)", False
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len("hello")
oHTTP.Send "test"
HTTPPost = oHTTP.ResponseText
MsgBox oHTTP.ResponseText
```

Output:

```
{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

Comment: Try `oHTTP.Send "content=test"` as it’s expecting posted form key value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `application/json` for your `Content-Type`, and send the body like this:

```json
{
    "content": "Test"
}
```

I am aware that you are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for your `Content-Type`. If I recall correctly, the API would only allow `application/json` if you're only sending text content and/or array of embeds, or `multipart/form-data` if you're also sending some files. I suspected that this is the case.

The other case, however, I'm not sure about what exactly `oHTTP.Send` does other than sending the request, but I am assuming it attaches the plain text data `"Test"` to the body of the request and the API did not recognize it because it required not just the property value, but also the property name.

You can always refer to [their docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) for future references.

Pardon for two things: First, for commenting using answers, I cannot use comment feature due to lack of reputation. Second, I'm not familiar using VBS at all despite quick research I have just done few moments ago, though I am a bit familiar with Discord webhook.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear [from the documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) that you can send a basic form POST.

> ##### Execute Webhook
>
> `POST/webhooks/{webhook.id}/{webhook.token}`
>
> ---
>
> Note that when sending a message, you must provide a value for at least one of `content`, `embeds`, or `file`.
>
> ---
>
> | Field | Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | content | string | the message contents (up to 2000 characters) |

To do this just adjust the code so you are sending a string key value pair e.g. `field1=value1&field2=value2` etc.

```
'Set text value to send as a variable so you can use it to set the content-length header.
Dim content: content = "hello"
Dim oHttp: Set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "POST", "(my webhook here)", False
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(content)
'Pass value as a form key value pair string.
oHTTP.Send "content=" & content
Dim response: response = oHTTP.ResponseText
Call MsgBox(response)
```